# Cisco ASR1006 Power usage

Tags: cisco, router, isp, cisco-asr

Hello everybody I hope all is well.

I was wondering if somebody can help?

I am trying to find a command to run for the power utilization on a ASR1006 using the following version of IOS-XE;

Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 03.12.00.S

Any ideas?

Cheers
Zi

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

IOS-XE could may be virtual i.e. on  CSR1000V and there is no power/environment options on this VM.

```
show platform hardware ?
crypto-device   crypto device information
interface       Interface information
network-clocks  Show network clock device
port            port information
qfp             Quantum Flow Processor
raid            raid information
slot            Slot information
subslot         Subslot information
throughput      Show throughput commands
```